# How did 'in-' + 'putare' compound to mean 'to attribute, credit to, impute'?

Tags: etymology

> [impute (v.):](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=impute&searchmode=none)
>   early 15c., from Old French *imputer* (14c.)
>   and directly from Latin *imputare* "to reckon, make account of, charge, ascribe,"
>   from assimilated form of ***in-*** "in, into" (see [in-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-&allowed_in_frame=0) (2)) +
>   ***putare*** "reckon, clear up, trim, prune, settle"  from PIE **puto-* "cut, struck," suffixed form of root **pau-* (2) "to cut, strike, stamp" (see [*pave*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pave&allowed_in_frame=0)).

[Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imputo#Latin0)

> Etymology[:]   
>   From [in-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-#Latin-in) +‎ [putō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puto#Latin) ‎(“esteem, consider”).
>
> 1. I reckon, charge, enter into the account.
> 2. (*figuratively*) I attribute, credit to; I impute

[This answer on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12417/5306) helpfully expounds the  Semantic Field of *putare*.

3. What are the semantic meaning and role of the prefix '*in-*' in *imputare*?
4. Please see the titled question.
   How did *in-* augment the semantic field of *putare*, to enable the semantic shift from 1 to 2?
   What semantic notions underlie 1 and 2?
5. 2 overhead contains 'to' in 'attribute, credit to'. So shouldn't *ad-* have been the prefix? I'm assuming that *in-* can't signify 'to'.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the semantic meaning and role of the prefix 'in-' in imputare?

*In-* literally means "towards", whilst *puto* is to reckon, and even calculate, compute. This results in "ascribing someone", "regarding someone to be the cause of something".

> How did in- augment the semantic field of putare, to enable the semantic shift from 1 to 2?
>   What semantic notions underlie 1 and 2?

The reason for the semantic shift from 1 to 2 should not be ascribed (XD) to the in- prefix, but instead to the meaning of the verb *imputare itself*, and to its usage. Though this word were mainly and firstly used in jurisprudence and finance, its usage was soon extended to moral and ethics. One can impute, assign something to someone concretely, but even figuratively assign to him a value or a disvalue (i.e. a crime).

> 2 overhead contains 'to' in 'attribute, credit to'. So shouldn't ad- have been the prefix? I'm assuming that in- can't signify 'to'

*In*- can signify to, towards, and it is even more direct than *ad*. In general, we say *in* if we know the exact destination of our action, we say *ad* to mean in the direction of, around the way to.